# Smart Contract Transaction Receive on Blockchain Wallet

Tags: transactions, ether

I received a transaction coming from a smart contract but Blockchain.info Wallet does not allow to use funds coming from smart contract.

I tried to import my private key on MyEtherWallet but the total amount of Ether is the same as on Blockchain.info Wallet

Who could explain to me how to retrieve the funds from the smart contract transaction?
Transaction on EtherScan:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x01b3f91e8a3d58e2492117b7a0e98f072197d968
On tab "Internal Transactions"

Thank!

Comment: Problem solved after looking at the old balance of my Wallet on EthScan from a different date I could see that my balance changed when I received the internal transaction (SmartContract) but no visible transaction